# Letter from the Chofetz Chaim about non religious martyrs

Tags: martyr, afterlife, chofetz-chaim, non-religious

I once heard that the **Chofetz Chaim** has a letter in which he writes that even someone who is totally non-religious, if they are killed because they are a Jew, they have a portion in the world to come as if they were religious. Since they identifed as a Jew (which is why they were killed), they're considered part of the fold.

Where can I find this letter? I skim read **Michtavei Chofetz Chaim** and didn't see anything remotely connected to this topic. But I definitely could have missed it.

Comment: I don't know this story from The Chafetz Haim, but I do now it from the Garsha"z Ouirbach.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84767/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I want the letter where the Chofetz Chaim says this. That question is if there's a source for such a concept. My question would answer that one, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a letter, but Reb Elchonon Wasserman is quoted [Here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22145&st=&pgnum=31) as telling his son to make a Bracha before they were killed by the nazis based on the Chofetz Chaim. Also, the Chofetz Chaim's grandson quoted him, as telling those killed because they were Jews in world war 1, to make a bracha before being killed even though it was not voluntary.

Rav Moshe Sternbuch [Teshuvos V'Hanhagos Vol. 5 pg.597] proves from this, that even if one is not given a choice, as long as he is being killed because he is a Jew, it is considered to be "Al Kiddush Hashem". I would say that would most likely get him a portion in the world to come.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22515/759

Comment: Maybe that's referring to a religious person?

Comment: Great sources and great references, but these answer a different question.